# paypal checkout display shipping costs but does not include them in transaction

Tags: paypal

I do not know if the issue is in code or the paypal account settings. Paypal displays correctly the shipping cost, it displays the correct total (item price + shipping), 
but in fact, the transactions includes only the item price, not the shipping costs.
I have been unable to find out what is wrong. if paypal can display it correctly, why cant it include it properly in the transaction ?

here is the request sent to paypal:

```
    $padata =   '&CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode).
            '&PAYMENTACTION=Sale'.
            '&ALLOWNOTE=1'.
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($TotalPrice).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
            '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0='. urlencode($ItemQty).
            '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0='.urlencode($ItemPrice).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.urlencode($deliveryCost).
            '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0='.urlencode($ItemName).
            '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0='.urlencode($ItemNumber).
            '&AMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
            '&RETURNURL='.urlencode($PayPalReturnURL ).
            '&CANCELURL='.urlencode($PayPalCancelURL);
```

The param for shipping that I used is :

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT
```

is it correct ? is a complementary one needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you supplying all of your `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_*` and `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_*` variables in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment call as well as your SetExpressCheckout call?

SetExpressCheckout will control what the buyer sees when they go to check out on PayPal.  DoExpressCheckoutPayment will control what the buyer is actually charged for.  Therefore, if you want your shipping charge to be included in the transaction, you need to make sure that it's included in both calls.

Comment: that was it, I copied code from the interwebs, with outdated params style. Thanks a zillion !

Answer (score 0):

for the records, correct params for DoExpressCheckoutPayment :

```
    $padata =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token).
            '&PAYERID='.urlencode($playerid).
            '&PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode("SALE").
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.urlencode($deliveryCost).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($TotalPrice).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
            '&CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode);
```